# cudf read csv file error : total size of strings is too large for cudf column

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, cudf

I use  colab and run cudf.read_csv() with a huge csv file (3GB, 17540000 records)，but the result is wrong.

```
import cudf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
g_df = cudf.read_csv('drive/MyDrive/m1.csv',escapechar="\\")
```

error message is

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-efc4c69ac697> in <module>()
----> 1 g_df = cudf.read_csv('drive/MyDrive/m1.csv',escapechar="\\")
      2 g_df.shape

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cudf/io/csv.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, header, mangle_dupe_cols, usecols, sep, delimiter, delim_whitespace, skipinitialspace, names, dtype, skipfooter, skiprows, dayfirst, compression, thousands, decimal, true_values, false_values, nrows, byte_range, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, comment, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, prefix, index_col, **kwargs)
    100         na_filter=na_filter,
    101         prefix=prefix,
--> 102         index_col=index_col,
    103     )
    104 

cudf/_lib/csv.pyx in cudf._lib.csv.read_csv()

RuntimeError: cuDF failure at: ../include/cudf/strings/detail/strings_column_factories.cuh:75: total size of strings is too large for cudf column
```

Comment: A single cudf string column can only hold a total of max(int32) individual characters. Use dask-cudf: https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/nightly/user_guide/10min.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas to read you CSV into chucks I take a sample form here [How do I read a large csv file with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas)

```py
chunksize = 10 ** 6
with pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        process(chunk)
```

I will recommend you to read it into chuck, if you did not do this its required a very high amount of memory and if you read in chuck you can save a lot of memeory this way.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with a file of similar size. After all the reason was I forgot to put delimiter parameter. It could be also your case, just try to put delimiter parameter when you call `read_csv`.